# If a countable infinity can be ‘counted’ by 1 counter working forever, can its powerset be counted by an infinity of counters working forever?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I realize an infinite set of Aleph-one cardinality is also known as uncountably infinite, but if you had a countably infinite set of counters to collectively assign to the task, could it be achieved? Would starting from the set for which its the powerset of help? Could I use the proof below on infinity ink at: http://www.ii.com/math/ch/#expCH

The set of reals between 0 and 1 can be represented by the set of all countably infinite sequences of 0's and 1's . Think of these as representing binary "decimals" between .000000... and .111111... . In this representation .1=1/2, .01=1/4, .11=3/4, etc.

The power set of the natural numbers, P(N), can also be represented by the set of all countably infinite sequences of 0's and 1's. Each sequence represents a subset of N by interpreting a 0 in position n to mean that the number n is not in the subset and a 1 in position n to mean the number n is in the subset. This way of specifying a set is called the "characteristic function" of the set.

One way to represent all countably infinite sequences of 0's and 1's is to use Cartesian product notation:

{0, 1} x {0, 1} x {0, 1} x ... = {0, 1}^aleph0
Since in set theory {0, 1} = 2, we can also write this as:
2^aleph0

thanks in advance!

Comment: A countable infinity of counters will only be able to count $\Bbb N^2$, which has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut:   They could count $\mathbb N^n$ for any finite $n$ (which is still countable), right?

Comment: Well, since it's again countable, certainly. As well as the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$. I picked $\Bbb N^2$ because there is an obvious way of viewing this: assign a number to each counter, then the counter $i$ counts $(i,j)$ for $j\in\Bbb N$. Since they all have different "objects" to count, they can't count anything larger (equipotency-wise).

Comment: Thanks for the replies and pardon my ignorance but would there be any way to organize a countable infinity of counters to take advantage of 2^Aleph 0 = Aleph 1?

Comment: I think no one knows that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, really.

Comment: Absolutely fair. But assuming CH could you take advantage of 2^ℵ0=ℵ1?

Comment: I think the question is answered without CH.

Comment: @DeaglánDunleavy There is now way to arrange a countable set to make it uncountable. "Arranging" would mean a bijection, hence the same cardinal, but it can be proved with [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) that $\mathrm{Card}\,\Bbb N^\Bbb N>\mathrm{Card}\,\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Jean-Claude. Did you notice I updated the question with a proof I found online? Surely if it is true as it says above: "The set of reals between 0 and 1 can be represented by the set of all countably infinite sequences of 0's and 1's" that would be a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, $2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$, the cardinality of the continuum. Now $\aleph_1 = \mathfrak{c}$ is exactly the Continuum Hypothesis.
Second, if by "an infinity of counters" you allow a non countable infinity, then yes :)
As for the question itself, since you are considering counters, and they can change their state at most a countable amount of times, then they won't be able to count to $\mathfrak{c}$.
Suppose they could, then we would have a uncountable amount of states our counters covered, which means at each step at least one of the counters changed its state, then by the Pigeon Hole Principle, since we have a countable set of counters and an uncountable amount of changes, so at least one of the counters must have chaged its state an uncountable amount of times. A contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the comment King. I understand that almost all methods of combining countable infinities together will leave you back with a countable infinity, but as you mention there is a way to get there thru 2^ℵ0= which is how the proof from infinite ink in the edited original post above gets there. Can you comment on why this proof above wouldn't work? thanks!

Comment: The thing is that you have counters, and they can change their state only a countable amount of times. In fact, there is a bijection between real numbers and possible configurations of the infinitely many counters, the problem is that even if you go on forever, you would not be able to reach all possible configurations. As in the proof, you would need a counter to change its state a uncountable amount of times, which I would assume is not possible.

Comment: One last thing I realized. Even with an uncountable amount of counters it is not that clear how to "count" all the reals. If your counters are all synchronized so they can only change their state every 1 second, then we would still have a countable amount of possible states our counters reach, which would correspond to a countable amount of numbers.